# KendoChart with stripes bars

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-chart

I am trying to create a KendoChart, then I wanted to have the bars to be on a stripes format.  How to do that?  I think I need to add "style" in "seriesDefaults" section or in the "series" section.

I have the code snippets below:

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
            title: {
                text: "Sample"
            },
            seriesDefaults: {
                type: "column"
            },
            series: [{
                name: "India",
                data: [3.907, 7.943, 7.848]
            },{
                name: "World",
                data: [1.988, 2.733, 3.994]
            }],
            valueAxis: {
                labels: {
                    format: "{0}%"
                },
                line: {
                    visible: false
                },
                axisCrossingValue: -10
            },
            categoryAxis: {
                categories: [2002, 2003, 2004],
                majorGridLines: {
                    visible: false
                },
                labels: {
                    rotation: "auto"
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                format: "{0}%",
                template: "#= series.name #: #= value #"
            }
        });
```

Comment: What is "strips format"? Can you post an image of the desired result?

Comment: I can't add an image ezanker.

Comment: Do you want the bars themselves to be striped? you can play around with the visual property: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/visuals

Comment: I really done this one, but with no luck at all.

Comment: maybe you can post an image of what you want at any image sharing site, and then provide a link to it here.

Comment: my account doesn't allow me to post an image.

Comment: you can post image to another site: http://webtrends.about.com/od/prof4/tp/Free-Image-Hosting-Sites-For-Photos.htm and then provide a link to the image here.